# How do I detect the length of `\t` and format it?

Tags: python, file, printing, io, format

I have a file

```
52779  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1  52779.jpg
278973  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1  278973.jpg
195284  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1  195284.jpg
19992  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1  19992.jpg
```

The file is created by IO in python(see below). I expect the length of each space is 1 `\t`. However, a test shows some of rows are ok, while others are not.

How can I detect the length of `\t` and format each space to `\t`?

---

Original file

```
204149 "0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1" 204149.jpg
52779 "0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1" 52779.jpg
278973 "0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1" 278973.jpg
195284 "0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1" 195284.jpg
```

What I did to the original file

```
fi = open('image.lst')
fi.readline()
fo = open('image2.lst', "w")
for line in fi:
    line = line.replace('"', ' ')   
    fo.write("%s" % line)
fi.close()
fo.close()
```

Comment: So you want to use tabs, or just tab-aligned spaces?

Comment: @will The output should be `2020 \t 12392 \t 12309`.

Comment: @JohnHass To be exact: `2020\t12392\t12309`. There shouldn't be spaces right?

Comment: @idjaw Yes, you are right.

Comment: @idjaw I used what you mentioned in possible duplicate. I understand it helps in many cases, but I want to make sure in this case what's the length of my space and fix them.

Comment: @JohnHass Yeah, that's why retracted the dupe flag. I realized it was slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "detecting the length of `'\t'`". `len('\t') == 1`, if that's what you mean... But in this line

```
line = line.replace('"', ' ')
```

you are replacing double quotes with one space, so you end up with spaces rather than `'\t'`.

Try this:

```
with open('image.lst') as fi, open('image2.lst', 'w') as fo:
    for line in fi:
        line = line.replace(' ', '\t').replace('"', '')
        fo.write(line)
```

An output line will be

```
204149\t0\t0\t0\t1\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1\t204149.jpg
```

Comment: For `1231\t2132`, the length is 1. For `1231\t\t2132`, the length is 2.

Comment: @JohnHass Well, it sounds like you want to count the *number* of `'\t'`s in a string. You can use `str.count` for that. But I don't think you'd need that for doing what you described in OP.